# How to execute Graphql Schema on Laravel Api Controller?

Tags: laravel, rest, graphql

I want to create a Rest API with Laravel, and on API controller i want to execute a particular Graphql schema, for example:
When I call this API

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/flight
```

I want that the API to execute this schema: `query{flight{flightNumber}}`

ps: I want them both to execute in the same project.

[image]

Comment: [Check out this github project](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql). Updated for laravel 5.7 and 1580 stars must mean they're doing something right.

Comment: It will help me to embed controller with Graphql like the schema above? because this is the work that I don't know how to do